# python-accessing the next object in database while in for loop

Tags: python, django

This is my view code. I iterate over all the entries in DB and when rollno matches, I want to store the student name for previous,current and next student in one go. Is there any way to implement it?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        rollno = request.POST.get('roll',None)
        studentlist = Students.objects.all()
        for st in studentlist:
          if st.roll_no == rollno:
             three_students=[*prev_student,current_student,next_student*]
```

Comment: How do you define "next"? Is roll_no always incremental?

Comment: @sayse, next means next student entry in db. yes, roll no has an increasing value

Comment: Can there be multiple matches to `st.roll_no == rollno`?

Comment: @sardorbek imomaliev, no it is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this is what you want

```
# create generator that will provide you with 3 neighobring students at the same time
def student_gen():
    triple = []    
    for s in Students.objects.all():
        triple.append(s)
        if len(triple) == 3:
            yield triple
            triple.pop(0)


# and inside your view
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    rollno = request.POST.get('roll',None)
    for three_students in student_gen():
        if three_students[1].roll_no == rollno:
            break
    print(three_students)
```

Comment: i want to store their names so after ' if three_students[1].roll_no == rollno: '  is this statement correct?

Comment: @user37886 you have all three student objects in `three_students` variable so you their names will be `three_students[0].name` etc.

Comment: i want to store their names so after ' if three_students[1].roll_no == rollno: ' is this statement correct?  names = [three_students[0].name, three_students[1].name, three_students[2].name] ?

Comment: @user37886 yes.

Comment: and where do i place the generator function?

Comment: @user37886 You can place it anywhere you want. Inside views.py is ok.

Comment: yes, just finished running it. though it has problem at end value, it works for all others (i'll work on it). thank you very much!

Comment: "local variable 'name' referenced before assignment". it shows this error for last entry in that print statement

Comment: @user37886 I think it would be better if you create separate question and add full tracelog and current code

Comment: there is just a minor mistake in the generator function, we have to add `yield triple` in else part too. otherwise there is no way i could access the 1st three students of the list (student at 0th position will be overriden)

Comment: @user37886 see I improved your edit. This is right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `roll_no` is incremental then you can just use `__in`

```
Student.objects.filter(roll_no__in=[roll_no - 1, roll_no, roll_no + 1])
```

If you can't guarrantee they're always incremental then you may need a separate query first to get the roll_no's you're trying to find first.

For example (without error/out of bounds handling),

```
rolls = Student.objects.order_by('roll_no').values_list('roll_no', flat=True)
idx = rolls.index(rollno)

rolls_to_filter_on = rolls[idx-1:3]
```

Comment: i am new to python so can you please explain where this statement will go. thanks !

Comment: `three_students = that_filter_code`, then it replaces your entire function pretty much