# filtering model of a table using filterset of another table-django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models:

```
class stations(models.Model):
    station_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True )
    station = models.CharField( max_length=20 )
    station_code = models.CharField( max_length=10 )
class route(models.Model):
    route_id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True )
class SequenceTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True )
    route_id = models.ForeignKey( route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station_id = models.ForeignKey(stations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_no = models.IntegerField( null=True )
```

I want to filter stations.objects (and fetch its fields) such that it contains stations of a given route_id only. So far I was able to write only this line which I guess is incorrect `st=stations.objects.filter(station_id=sequence.objects.filter(route_id=rid))`

Please help me find a correct solution to it

Comment: Show us your models please.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, It is as i have written above. 3 models-stations,route,sequence and their fields are mentioned in braces

Comment: I need to know what type of fields you are using. `ForeignKey` or `CharField`?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev,please check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
station_ids = SequenceTable.objects.filter(route_id=rid).values_list('station_id', flat=True)

station_qs = stations.objects.filter(station_id__in=station_ids)
```

This will generate only one DB query because of how django's querysets are implemented.

**Answering comment.** Yes you can here is exmaple(may not work) that will give you general idea

```
def station_gen(rid):
    triple = []
    station_ids = SequenceTable.objects.filter(route_id=rid).values_list('station_id', flat=True)
    for s in stations.objects.filter(station_id__in=station_ids):
        if len(triple) == 3:
            triple.pop(0)
            triple.append(s)
            yield triple
        else:
            triple.append(s)

# and inside your view
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    rid = request.POST.get('rid',None)
    for three_students in student_gen(rid):
        ...
    print(three_students)
```

Comment: thats quite an easy way. but i have one lingering question. in my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40014953/4586638 which u answered (pls replace rollno by station_id and student model by station model) can i use ur ans in the generator function?

Comment: or should i store station_qs in session and then use it in that generator function?